Invalid configuration found in /Users/nickk/Documents/Pioneer_Frontend/components.json
In the svelte framework I installed Shadcn UI library and installed three of it's components but now when I try to install any other library it gives me this error.
Component.json file looks like this -
{
    "$schema": "https://shadcn-svelte.com/schema.json",
    "style": "default",
    "tailwind": {
        "config": "tailwind.config.ts",
        "css": "src/app.css",
        "baseColor": "slate"
    },
    "aliases": {
        "components": "$lib/components",
        "utils": "$lib/utils"
    },
    "typescript": true
}

I deleted node package, package-lock.json and reinstalled all and also installed shadcn again but it doesn't solves my issue.
I changed my theme.ts file but I don't think it has to do something with the issue.

I've got same problem when occasionally tried to instal shadcn component not shadcn svelte component on my svelte project

Thanks! In my case I was installing the input by incorrectly using npx shadcn-ui@latest add input instead of npx shadcn-svelte@latest add input

It's exactly what i'm talking about - original Shadcn lib is made for React (you calling it with npx shadcn-ui@latest add ) while  npx shadcn-svelte obviously is for Svelte. I did the same mistake
